# Angular two way data binding not working when $scope is updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a really serious problem, I'm updating, editing, deleting data, and the two-way data binding is not working.

This is one of my controllers:

```
'use strict';
var EventController = function($timeout, $scope, $state, EventModel) {
    this.$timeout   = $timeout;
    this.$scope         = $scope;
    this.$state         = $state;
    this.EventModel = EventModel;

    /**
     * When the page is requested, retrieve all the data.
     *
     */
    this.retrieve();
};

EventController.prototype = {
    create: function(event) {
        var that = this;
        this.EventModel.Model.insert(event)
            .then(function() {
                that.refresh();
            });
    },

    retrieve: function() {
        var that = this;
        this.EventModel.Model.find()
            .then(function(result) {
                that.$scope.events = result;
            });
    },

    one: function(id) {
        var that = this;
        this.EventModel.Model.one(id)
            .then(function(result) {
                that.$scope.event = result;
            });
    },

    update: function(id, event, state) {
        if (state !== undefined) {
            event.is_active = state;
        }

        var that = this;
        this.EventModel.Model.update(id, event)
            .then(function() {
                that.refresh();
            });
    },

    delete: function(id) {
        var check = $('[data-controller-input]:checked');
        var that    = this;

        $.each(check, function() {
            var target  = $(this);
            var id          = target.prop('id');

            that.EventModel.Model.remove(id)
                .then(function() {
                    that.refresh();
                });
        });
    },

    clear: function() {
        this.$scope.event = angular.copy(this.$scope.initial);
    },

    refresh: function() {
        this.$state.go(this.$state.current, {}, {reload: true});
    }
};

angular
    .module('adminApp')
    .controller('EventController',
        [
            '$timeout',
            '$scope',
            '$state',
            'EventModel',
            EventController
        ]
);
```

In the create, update and delete methods I need to update the HTML without refreshing the page, I already tried using, $scope.apply, $scope.digest, $timeout after the result came, but not happens in the HTML.

If I try $scope.apply and $scope.digest the error will be:

```
Prevent error $digest already in progress when calling $scope.$apply()
```

So I was trying to wrap the $scope.$apply or $digest with the $timeout, same result, nothing happens.

Thanks.

Comment: try $evalAsync, or $applyAsync or $$postDigest.

Comment: could you elaborate better?

Comment: How was the promise returned by `EventModel.Model.insert(event)` created?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your refresh method will never update your controller.it will simply fail just because `this.$state.current` won't be able to resolve any url ,template or controller.

And this is the main reason you are not able to see updated data ,just check your console you might be getting `Error: Cannot transition to abstract state '[object Object]'` error.

**Update : I have create a  plnkr.as i don't have access to event model code i simply removed it  and try to create the same scenario.**

http://plnkr.co/edit/RsI3TgKwcjGEXcTMKoQR?p=preview

see if this can help you

Comment: why will fail? could you explain better?

Comment: try to call create method and then see the console.you will see the error

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but try using the following function which checks the current phase before executing your function. It may solve the issue.

```
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
  var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
  if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
    if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
      fn();
    }
  } else {
    this.$apply(fn);
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
$scope.safeApply(function() {
  //Your lines
});
```